# IEEE Rounding schemes

Tags: floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

I am trying to learn the features of IEEE rounding from the following source [On fast IEEE Rounding](ftp://reports.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/csl/tr/91/459/CSL-TR-91-459.pdf)

[image]
Can anyone one explain the equation for round up ? What does round up with fix up mean ? And what are floor and ceiling functions ? I tried IEEE 754 , but it does not mention these

Comment: Since you first sentence indicates you are trying to learn about IEEE rounding (presumably IEEE 754, the floating-point standard) from that paper, it should be noted that the paper is not about IEEE-754 rounding. It is about implementing IEEE-754 rounding using features in certain computer processing hardware. Largely, the paper is not about the mathematical properties of IEEE 754 but is about designing computer processing hardware. A better place to learn about IEEE-754 is the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#CITEREFIEEE_7542008)…

Comment: or [the official standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57469) (which has a fee) or [*Handbook of Floating-point Arithmetic* by Muller et al](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Floating-Point-Arithmetic-Jean-Michel-Muller/dp/081764704X).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with floor( ) and ceiling( ) (which I'm going to call "ceil" from here on).  These are basic mathematical functions which map real numbers to integers.  Formally, they are defined as follows:

```
floor(x) = max { n in Z | n <= x }
ceil(x) = min { n in Z | n >= x }
```

More plainly, the floor of `x` is the largest integer that is no bigger than `x`, and the ceil is the smallest integer that is no smaller than `x`.  Some examples:

- `floor(1.5)` is `1`.
- `ceil(2)` is `2`.
- `floor(-3.14159)` is `-4`.

Consult [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for more details.

Ok, now lets move on to rounding.  Every real number x either *is* an integer (in which case `floor(x) == x == ceil(x)`), or lies between two integers `floor(x) < x < ceil(x)`.  Mathematically, a "rounding rule" is a function `f` that maps real numbers to integers with the following property: for every real number `x`, `f(x) = floor(x)` or `f(x) = ceil(x)`.  This leaves lots of flexibility about which possible result is chosen in any situation, so there are lots of different rounding rules.  Here are some examples ([these certainly aren't exhaustive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer)):

- each of `floor( )` and `ceil( )` is a rounding rule.
- "round toward zero": simply throw away the fractional part of the input.  This is also called *truncation*, and is often written as a mathematical function called `trunc( )`.  It can be defined as `trunc(x) = ceil(x)` if `x < 0`, and `trunc(x) = floor(x)` otherwise*.  For example, `trunc(1.5)` is `1` and `trunc(-2.7)` is `-2`.
- "round away from zero" or "round towards infinity": This is the "opposite" of truncation; if `x < 0` the result is `floor(x)`, and the result is `ceil(x)` otherwise.  There isn't a common mathematical name for this rule, so I'll just call it `round-away( )`.  Examples: `round-away(1.001)` is `2`, and `round-away(-0.7071067812)` is `-1`.
- "round to odd": If the input `x` is an integer, return `x`.  Otherwise, look at `floor(x)` and `ceil(x)`.  Because they are consecutive integers, one of them will be even and the other will be odd.  Return the one that is odd.  Some examples: `round-to-odd(1.001)` is `1`, `round-to-odd(-2.001)` is `-3`, and `round-to-odd(4.0)` is `4.0`.
- "round to nearest, ties to even": This is the default rounding mode of IEEE-754.  I would call it `round( )`, but that name is (rather perversely) used for a different rounding rule in the C library, and I don't want to confuse everyone, so I'll call it `rne( )` instead here.  Here the idea is as follows: if there is a unique integer closest to `x`, return that integer.  Otherwise, `x` lies exactly halfway between two integers; one of them is even and the other is odd.  Return the even one.

This last rule can be written as "RU with fix-up", though that is a somewhat odd way to think of it, mathematically.  More commonly, it's formally defined more or less as follows:

```
rne(x) = floor(x)  if x - floor(x) < 0.5
         floor(x)  if x - floor(x) = 0.5 and floor(x) is even.
         ceil(x)   if x - floor(x) = 0.5 and floor(x) is odd.
         ceil(x)   if x - floor(x) > 0.5
```

Some examples of this `rne( )` rule in action: `rne(0.5)` is `0`.  `rne(-1.5)` is `-2`.  `rne(1.3)` is `1`.  `rne(1.8)` is `2`.

Ok, so this is all talking about *rounding to integral values*.  What does that have to do with rounding to the nearest floating-point number as in IEEE-754?  A rounding rule may be used not only to round to integer, but to round to any fixed number of digits as well, by simply scaling it by a factor of `b**n`, where `b` is the base of the representation and `n` is chosen so that the desired rounding point of the number ends up in the units position (the LSB).  Of course, we don't actually need to scale the number and un-scale the result; instead we simply replace `ceil(x)` and `floor(x)` in the rounding rule with the values of `x` rounded down and up to the desired number of digits.

[*] I'm defining *mathematical* functions on real numbers here, not giving IEEE-754 implementations.  Thus, there's no need to deal with edge cases like `-0`, `inf`, or `nan`.